# Standard image DB to test image classification

Tags: database, image, classification, cbir

Is there some list of standard image data bases that can be used to test image classification? This means DB that can be used to test CBIR systems like the WANG Database.
It would be very helpful to have some description of the DB (what you can find inside) and possibility to download it if it is free.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This list](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/Imagedbase.htm) could probably help you.

Comment: Thanks, that is a good list. I will try something there later. For this time I have found some databases here http://www.face-rec.org/databases/